# Token list of counter values

Tags: counters, expansion, programming

I am trying to collect certain counter values in a list of tokens. Here is my naive attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtoks\list
\list={}

\def\addtolist#1{\global\list=\expandafter{\the\list #1}}

\newcounter{counter}
\def\countertolist{\expandafter\addtolist{\arabic{counter}}}

\begin{document}

\stepcounter{counter}
\stepcounter{counter}
\countertolist
\stepcounter{counter}
\stepcounter{counter}
\countertolist

\the\list

\end{document}
```

I would like the result to be 24 but it is 44. It seems that in the definition of `\countertolist` the `\arabic{counter}` is not 'expanded enough' (i.e. not expanded when `\countertolist` is used). What is the right definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason is that `\arabic{counter}` is not expanded enough. This can be changed to `\expandafter\addtolist\expandafter{\the\c@counter}` to force the expansion.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtoks\list
\list={}

\def\addtolist#1{\global\list=\expandafter{\the\list #1}}

\newcounter{counter}
\makeatletter
\def\countertolist{\expandafter\addtolist\expandafter{\the\c@counter}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\stepcounter{counter}
\stepcounter{counter}
\countertolist
\stepcounter{counter}
\stepcounter{counter}
\countertolist

\the\list

\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe it should be pointed out that \newtoks\list may be a rather unfortunate choice (try adding something like \begin{center} or \begin{itemize} ... to the above document :-)

Comment: @FrankMittelbach: Thanks for suggestion -- I would not use a token list here at all, but that's the choice of the O.P.

Comment: that too, but that is a choice of the OP as you say. However redefining list means he wasn't aware of what he overwrites and that might just cause the next question afterwards

Comment: @FrankMittelbach: I will update with a usual `\xdef\foo{\foo ...}` method or something what the `\@cons` approach does with counter lists, for example